# issue with multiple instances of jPlayer in FF and IE

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jplayer

i have a page that calls for multiple instances of jplayer. everything works fine in Chrome/Safari, but in FF and IE, the first instance of the player loads the 'play' button and progress bar, but the audio doesn't work.

for the 2nd and 3rd instance, the 'play' button is there, but there's no progress bar, and no audio.  i'm 90% sure this is an issue with my js file, which looks like this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

$("#jquery_jplayer_1").jPlayer({
  ready: function () {
      $(this).jPlayer("setMedia", {
        mp3: "media/demo.mp3"
      });
    },
    ended: function (event) {
      $(this);
    },
    supplied: "mp3"
  }).bind($.jPlayer.event.play, function() { // Using a jPlayer event to avoid both jPlayers playing together.
  $(this).jPlayer("pauseOthers");
});

$("#jquery_jplayer_2").jPlayer({
  ready: function () {
    $(this).jPlayer("setMedia", {
      mp3: "media/English_Commercial Demo.mp3"
    });
  },
  ended: function (event) {
    $(this);
  },
  cssSelectorAncestor:"#jp_interface_2",
  supplied: "mp3"
  }).bind($.jPlayer.event.play, function() { 
  $(this).jPlayer("pauseOthers");
});

$("#jquery_jplayer_3").jPlayer({
  ready: function () {
    $(this).jPlayer("setMedia", {
      mp3: "media/English_Narration_Demo.mp3"
    });
  },
  ended: function (event) {
    $(this);
  },
  cssSelectorAncestor:"#jp_interface_3",
  supplied: "mp3"
  }).bind($.jPlayer.event.play, function() { 
  $(this).jPlayer("pauseOthers");
});
```

and heres the html:

```
<div class="players">
        <div class="jp-audio">
          <div class="jp-type-single">
                <div id="jquery_jplayer_1" class="jp-jplayer"></div>
                <div id="jp_interface_1" class="jp-interface">
                    <ul class="jp-controls">
                        <li><a href="#" class="jp-play" tabindex="1">play</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#" class="jp-pause" tabindex="1">pause</a></li>
                    </ul>
                    <div class="jp-progress">
                        <div class="jp-seek-bar">
                            <div class="jp-play-bar"></div>
                        </div>
                </div>
                </div>
          </div>
</div>


 <div class="players">
        <div class="jp-audio">
          <div class="jp-type-single">
                <div id="jquery_jplayer_2" class="jp-jplayer">
                </div>
                <div id="jp_interface_2" class="jp-interface">
                    <ul class="jp-controls">
                        <li><a href="#" class="jp-play" tabindex="1">play</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#" class="jp-pause" tabindex="1">pause</a></li>
                    </ul>
                    <div class="jp-progress2">
                        <div class="jp-seek-bar">
                        <div class="jp-play-bar">
                        </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div> 

 <div class="jp-audio">
          <div class="jp-type-single">
                <div id="jquery_jplayer_3" class="jp-jplayer"></div>
                <div id="jp_interface_3" class="jp-interface">
                    <ul class="jp-controls">
                        <li><a href="#" class="jp-play" tabindex="1">play</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#" class="jp-pause" tabindex="1">pause</a></li>
                    </ul>
                    <div class="jp-progress2">
                        <div class="jp-seek-bar">
                            <div class="jp-play-bar">
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
          </div>
        </div>
```

i've removed some of the inline styling and other extraneous things like Download buttons, but can add the full code if this is too confusing/ugly (i'm sure theres an extra  in there somewhere).

Answer (score 3):

- Neither Firefox nor IE will play an MP3 file unless you supply a valid `swfPath`.
- You are supplying a `.jp-interface` element as the CSS Ancestor but this is incorrect - you need to supply  "the cssSelector of an ancestor of all cssSelectors" (see [the docs](http://www.jplayer.org/latest/developer-guide/#jPlayer-option-cssSelectorAncestor))

try the changes to your code i made in [this Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/75lb/YAe4g/) - see if it works for you.

the new HTML markup looks like this

```
<div class="players">
    <div id="jp_container_1" class="jp-audio">
        <div class="jp-type-single">
            <div id="jquery_jplayer_1" class="jp-jplayer"></div>
            <div id="jp_interface_1" class="jp-interface">
                <ul class="jp-controls">
                    <li><a href="#" class="jp-play" tabindex="1">play</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#" class="jp-pause" tabindex="1">pause</a></li>
                </ul>
                <div class="jp-progress">
                    <div class="jp-seek-bar">
                        <div class="jp-play-bar"></div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="players">
    <div id="jp_container_2" class="jp-audio">
        <div class="jp-type-single">
            <div id="jquery_jplayer_2" class="jp-jplayer"></div>
            <div id="jp_interface_2" class="jp-interface">
                <ul class="jp-controls">
                    <li><a href="#" class="jp-play" tabindex="1">play</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#" class="jp-pause" tabindex="1">pause</a></li>
                </ul>
                <div class="jp-progress">
                    <div class="jp-seek-bar">
                        <div class="jp-play-bar"></div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="players">
    <div id="jp_container_3" class="jp-audio">
        <div class="jp-type-single">
            <div id="jquery_jplayer_3" class="jp-jplayer"></div>
            <div id="jp_interface_3" class="jp-interface">
                <ul class="jp-controls">
                    <li><a href="#" class="jp-play" tabindex="1">play</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#" class="jp-pause" tabindex="1">pause</a></li>
                </ul>
                <div class="jp-progress">
                    <div class="jp-seek-bar">
                        <div class="jp-play-bar"></div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

and the new Javascript:

```
$("#jquery_jplayer_1").jPlayer({
    swfPath: "http://www.jplayer.org/latest/js/Jplayer.swf",
    ready: function () {
        $(this).jPlayer("setMedia", { mp3: "http://www.freesfx.co.uk/rx2/mp3s/3/2665_1315685839.mp3" });
    },
    play: function () { $(this).jPlayer("pauseOthers"); },
    supplied: "mp3"
});

$("#jquery_jplayer_2").jPlayer({
    swfPath: "http://www.jplayer.org/latest/js/Jplayer.swf",
    ready: function () {
        $(this).jPlayer("setMedia", { mp3: "http://www.freesfx.co.uk/rx2/mp3s/3/2664_1315685834.mp3" });
    },
    play: function () { $(this).jPlayer("pauseOthers"); },
    cssSelectorAncestor:"#jp_interface_2",
    supplied: "mp3"
});

$("#jquery_jplayer_3").jPlayer({
    swfPath: "http://www.jplayer.org/latest/js/Jplayer.swf",
    ready: function () {
        $(this).jPlayer("setMedia", { mp3: "http://www.freesfx.co.uk/rx2/mp3s/3/2660_1315685820.mp3" });
    },
    play: function () { $(this).jPlayer("pauseOthers"); },
    cssSelectorAncestor:"#jp_interface_3",
    supplied: "mp3"
});
```

Comment: thanks lloyd! your code makes total sense, but unfortunately when i apply to my code, it still doesn't work in FF and IE. i'm totally missing something here. here's the site with your code: http://www.hireliz.com/lizn3wsite/index.html

Comment: odd.. yes, i can see what's happening.. try using a more recent version of jQuery - version 1.6.4 ideally.. let me know..

Comment: hmm ok, using 1.6.4 now, but still nothing :( any other ideas would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

FF doesn't actually play MP3 files but instead plays OGG files.  If the demo songs in the above corrected example code from Lloyd works but when you change the MP3 path to an MP3 file on your server and it doesn't work then make sure your server has the MIME type "application/ogg" (without quotes).  The server will see the MP3 file in the code and play it as if it were an OGG application file.  I'm not sure why this works on my server.  This is not my discovery but rather a tip I found on the Internet.  Hope it works for you.

Also make sure the HTML head has Lloyd's new Javascript and is wrapped like this:

```
<head>

  <script type='text/javascript' src='http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.6.4.js'></script>
  <script type='text/javascript' src="http://www.jplayer.org/latest/js/jquery.jplayer.min.js"></script>

<script type='text/javascript'>

//<![CDATA[ 
$(function(){

      Lloyd's javascript code goes here

});
//]]>  

</script>

</head>
```

Tip: Click on Lloyd's "fiddle" link - the "Play" links work.

Answer (score 0):

i don't know why it dosn't work in ie... but opera and ff don't play mp3 file

```
swfPath: "js",
supplied: "mp3",
wmode: "window"
```

In order to play them, there is Jplayer.swf file in js folder. You should write swfPath: "write the track of Jplayer.swf"...